# Is there a way for the showTimePicker() in Flutter to not reset any value in TextInputField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I implemented a page in my Flutter application that has a text input field and 2 time pickers that are activated by pressing the button to make them appear. The issue is that if I have a new value in the TextInputField and use one of the time pickers, after I'm done what I have typed in the input field will just reset.

Code snippet from the input field:

```
SizedBox(
            width: 350,
            child: TextField(
              controller: titleController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Title',
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                title = value;
              },
            ),
          ),
```

I've tried keeping the value of what is being typed in through a titleController and I have also attempted using the onChanged() method and a separate variable to keep the value in there. These solutions both didn't work for me, however. Is there any other solution to this issue?

Comment: Are you not using a stateful widget?

Answer (score 0):

If your `TextField` inside a stateless widget it will keep clearing the value of the controller everytime something pop on the screen, so try to put your TextField inside a stateful widget

Comment: The TextField is inside of a stateful widget, so I don't think this can be the issue unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you please show your full code